# curl command in linux

Tags: linux, curl, ubuntu-14.04

How we can add JSON parameters in a curl command to fetch data ?
PS: I have tried to fetch data from some source using curl command but it requires passing JSON parameters in it. So how I will accomplish it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think mentioning content type as json and passing data will do the things right

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}' http://domain.com/rest/path/here
```

Above will work for GET Method,  for POST method

```
 curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}' http://domain.com/rest/path/here
```